# How to make a nick change command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I've been trying to make a nickname command, but everytime, it shows me this error : discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
I have Administrator permission and even without i can't.
Here is my code :

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(change_nickname=True)
async def nick(ctx, nickname : str):
    await ctx.author.edit(nick=nickname)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention}, your name was sucessfully changed to {nickname} !")
```

Thanks for futur anwsers !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such permissions as `change_nickname` it's `manage_nicknames`

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_nicknames=True)
...
```

Comment: discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions Still having this error

Comment: Are you sure? Are you also sure you have the right permissions? Works flawlessly for me

Comment: A friend tried with his accound and SAME permission as me, and it worked for him ! Maybe because im the owner ?

Comment: I doubt that, that's not how discord works, maybe it's a bug (?) or your permissions are messed up

Comment: Also if you're trying to change the nick for yourself it won't work, the owner of the guild is always at the top of the hierarchy, the bot won't be able to edit you